# Spring MVC - Instantiate nested object only when input is filled

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have these models:

```
@Entity
public class User {
     //...
    @NotBlank private String login;
    @NotBlank private String password;
    @Valid @OneToOne private Person person;
     //...
}

// And

@Entity
public class Person {
     //...  
    @NotBlank private String name;
     //...
}
```

And this insert method in User controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
public String insert(@Valid User user, BindingResult result){

}
```

And this form

```
<p>Login : <input type="text" name="login" /></p>
<p>Pass : <input type="text" name="password" /></p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" name="person.name" /></p>
```

Association between Person and User is Optional. So don't need to fill `person.name` input.

But when controller receive User's information `@Valid` annotation is validating both User and Person objects even `person.name` is empty.

I realized that Controller is receiving Person object instance always.

Is it possible to receive null in Person when `person.name` input is not filled?

When I remove `person.name` input from the form, its OK, I receive null. But peson name is optional and I cant remove from form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove @NotBlank at Person Name :

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    private String name;

}
```

Comment: Thank to reply. OK, its work because Person's instance don't pass through validation. I need to validate presence of name (in other insert form). The problem: I'm still receiving person's objects even if its inputs are empty. The correct would not generate person instance if I don't fill person.name, right?. Thanks

Comment: i think it because u got <input type="text" name="person.name" /> in your code. how if you delete that input? is it work?

Comment: Or you can do some trick with javascript. fill person.name with a space if your user dont fill it. do it on submit.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Spring never send null object when I have input with "person.name", even I don't fill this input. Spring bind it to instance of Person. I want to Spring send me null in Person when I don't fill "person.name" input. But it seems it is impossible :(.